# Can't Un-disable checkbox after submit that have get its value from DB

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I need your help about my problem. I've two table with checkbox, the first is show all the record from DB (using MySQL) and the second table get the data after I checked and submit from the first table.So I want to disable my checkbox in the first table after I checked and submitted the data to the second table, but if I want cancel the copy I check the second table so the checkbox in the first table will be enabled and the data in the second table will erase (because it just temporary variable for store another DB). In this code I'm using `disable` but it can't work where is the problem?

```html
// this code for checked the checkbox that be chosen first
session_start();
  if (count($_POST)){
   //save choices to session
          $_SESSION['select_DB']=$_POST['select_DB'];
  }

  function was_checked($i) {
    if ($_SESSION['select_DB']){
     if(in_array($i,$_SESSION['select_DB']) ) {
        return "checked='checked'";
     }
    }
    return "";
  }

  ?>
```

```js
 // this one if cancel the submit
<script>
  function openCB() {
      document.getElementById("balik_DB[]").disabled = false;
  }
  </script>
  
 
//i'm using this to disable checkbox after submit  
  <script>
  function closeCB() {
      document.getElementById("balik_DB[]").disabled = true;
  }
  </script>
```

```html
   <!-- This code show table with checkbox that its value get from DB--> 
    <tbody>


          <?php
              include "db_connect.php";

              $sql_select = $dt_bas->prepare("SELECT id_pegawai, nm_pegawai, tmp_lahir FROM pegawai");
              $sql_select->execute();

              while($row = $sql_select->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
                        $id =  $row["id_pegawai"]; // id
                        $nm =  $row["nm_pegawai"]; // employe name
                        $tmp = $row["tmp_lahir"]; // birthday
        ?>
            <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="select_DB[]" id="select_DB[]" value=<?php echo"$id";?> <?=was_checked($id)?>/></td>
            <td><?php echo "$id";?></td>
            <td><?php echo "$nm";?></td>
            <td><?php echo "$tmp";?></td>
            <td>
                <a href="#">Ubah</a>
                <a href="#">Detail</a>
            </td>
            </tr>

        <?php    } ?>
        </tbody>
```

```html
<!--this the second table that get its value from the first table-->
<form>

      <table border="1">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Nama</th>
                <th>TTL</th>
                <th>Aksi</th>
              </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <?php
                // this code for get the data that is chosen from checkbox
                include "db_connect.php";

                if(isset($_POST['select_DB'])){
                   foreach($_POST['select_DB'] as $select=>$option_id){
                      $sql_select2 = $dt_bas->prepare("SELECT id_pegawai, nm_pegawai,  tmp_lahir FROM pegawai WHERE id_pegawai = '$option_id' ");
                      $sql_select2->execute();

                      while($row = $sql_select2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
                        $id =  $row["id_pegawai"]; // id
                        $nm =  $row["nm_pegawai"]; // employee name
                        $tmp = $row["tmp_lahir"]; // birth place
                        ?>

                    <tr>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" id="balik_DB[]" value="<?php echo"$id";?>"/></td>
                    <td><?php echo"$id";?></td>
                    <td><?php echo"$nm";?></td>
                    <td><?php echo"$tmp";?></td>
                    <td>
                          <a href="#">Ubah</a>
                          <a href="#">Detail</a>
                    </td>
                    </tr>
            <?php          }
                    }
                }
                ?>


              </tbody>
              <tfooter>
              </tfooter>
      </table>
  <input type="submit" value="Balik" onclick="openCB()"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem in `id="balik_DB[]"` because you fetch data from the database and dynamically create checkbox so what will happen when more than one checkbox would have same 'id'(id should be unique).So instead of using id ,you need to use `class = "balik_DB[]"`.

Comment: thank you @ShivamRajput, I'm gonna try what U suggest

Comment: could you help me once again? just as you said I've tried but the problem is how I can get the specific id that I choose from checkbox, 'class' give array as the output so if I want to get the value I must get the specific 'index' from  'class', How I can get the specific index from the checkbox I choose because the loop will give data as long as the DB have it, Would you mind write it in code?

Comment: you can bind a event on class balik_DB[] like this:

$("body").on('click',''balik_DB[]",function(){
var id = $(this).attr(''value") //for gettting value of checked box

{
  // write show and hide code here
}

})

Comment: if you don't understand so call me on skype my id is shivamrajputcane
,Iwill help you as soon as possible.